# How is this node library able to send me an email from any (possibly owned) domain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

I've been playing around with the library found here: https://github.com/guileen/node-sendmail

It's able to send an email that appears in my mailbox, though it will appear to come from any domain I specify, even existing ones with authentication layers...

For example:

```
var sendmail = require('sendmail')();

sendmail({
    from: 'no-reply@yourdomain.com',
    to: 'test@qq.com, test@sohu.com, test@163.com ',
    subject: 'test sendmail',
    html: 'Mail of test sendmail ',
  }, function(err, reply) {
    console.log(err && err.stack);
    console.dir(reply);
});
```

I've found that setting 'from' to an existing email (that I don't own) will sometimes work in that I will receive that email with that address as a from address.
I've found that replying to these emails sends the response to the original owner of the email...

How is any of this possible without being a security breach? What kind of email am I sending here? Would this be considered a reasonable way to send emails through NodeJS?

Comment: Note that it's not just that library, and not just Node, that allows that sort of thing.

Comment: sendmail sends the email using the SMTP server of the recipient - so it's **your** SMTP server that is accepting such mail

Comment: Sure, but how is this possible? Is it safe to use or is this some kind of pseudo email I'm sending here? Sorry I'm very new to this stuff.

Comment: So I can't seem to send an email this way to a Hotmail account, is that because hotmail blocks that sort of thing?

Comment: I imagine the big email providers like gmail, and even hotmail, would secure their SMTP servers against such traffic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called email spoofing and it not related to the NodeJS library implementation. The original [SMTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) does not provide any mechanism to prevent this.

However, a later RFC titled [Sender ID: Authenticating E-Mail](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4406) introduced a mechanism called SPF (Sender Policy Framework) that prevent sending bogus sender details.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFPYrAr1boU) explains how SPF works very clearly. Simply the email client (e.g. Gmail) can establish a connection with the domain that is called SMTP conversation to ensure the validity of the email.

In addition to SPF, these days many domain owners use DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) that further prevent bogus sender. This is basically how DKIM works:

1. The domain owner uses a public/private key pair that will be used when sending messages.
2. When authorized user sends an email, the server uses the private key to generate a digital signature of the message. The receiver server can use this signature to verify the email.

If you are not familiar with the concept of public keys and private keys, I definitely recommend you to watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QnD2c4Xovk). It is a really interesting method to communicate securely between two servers without risking the man in the middle to eavesdrop on the conversation.